# Limit of a function as accumulation point

Tags: analysis, limits

In the context of [this answer to another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/180396/34930) about representing I thought of the following possible description of the limit of a function:

$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=y$ iff $(a,y)$ is an accumulation point of $f$ (interpreted as a set of pairs) and there's no $y′≠y$ so that $(a,y′)$ is also an accumulation point of $f$.

Now my question is: Is that claim correct?

Comment: Well, first of all, you would need that $(a,y)$ is an accumulation point, since $x$ is a bound variable in the expression. (And similarly, $(a,y')$...) Not sure if that is enough to make the statements equivalent.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I'll immediately fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work in a compact space, in which values $y'$ that don't tend to the limit have to have some other accumulation point. However, if the space is not compact, there need no be a second accumulation point. For instance, the function

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}1/x&1/x\in\mathbb N\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

has no limit for $x\to0$, but according to your description it would, since $(0,0)$ is the only accumulation point of the set of pairs.

Comment: So if I first compactify the codomain of $f$, then it works?

Comment: @celtschk: Yes, I think so.